# Way to figure out / retrieve Windows username in Oracle APEX

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle-apex

I wanted to know, if there is a way to just get the Windows username with some kind of function, ... in Oracle APEX 4.2 an populate it a `Display Only` element in an application page. I don't want to do a login authentification, I just want to get the username.

On the Oracle Database you could do something like

```
  SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER') "USERNAME"
  FROM dual;
```

to get it. Is there a similar way for APEX?

Comment: Even if there were a way you'd have to make it platform independent (ideally). The user may use a Mac instead of Windows or even Linux (although chances of OS cross-platform in a corporate environment is less, but it's still a possibility)

Comment: +1 for mentioning this, haven't thought about it. Bus as far as I know all PCs/Laptops use Windows and just some few people will be using the application where I need to get this information and they all use Windows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most browsers on Windows won't let the web site interrogate things like the user's login name. I think you'd need to run something on the client that would need the user's permission to run.

Answer (score 0):

### ActiveX (IE only)

For clients with Internet Explorer then you can identify the windows username through an ActiveX control. There are security requirements to allow the ActiveX to run on the users browser, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179185/using-activex-to-get-username).

To implement this in Apex you would create a dynamic action that runs the ActiveX & javascript on page load to retrieve the username and the set a page item value using the JS API

```
var net = new ActiveXObject ( "WScript.NetWork" );
var username = net.UserName;
$s('P123_HIDDEN_USERNAME',username);
```

### From the Web Server

You may be able to retrieve the OS username at the application server level as described in [this post on the Oracle Forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1083271) - using either weblogic or mod_ntlm/mod_auth_kerberos.  Even if not using for authentication it maybe possible to retrieve the username into an application level item at the start of a session.

This solution would be quite involved however and require access to configure the application server hosting your Apex listener.