# Triggers not capturing values of SYS_CONTEXT from Oracle APEX Application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table with `BEFORE INSERT ROW` trigger. When I insert into this table via SQL*plus on backend, it correctly captures value of `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER')`.

But when row is inserted from an (Oracle) APEX application, the OS_USER field in table is not populated.

Trigger Code is given below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER db_req_trg
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON db_req
    REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
       IF INSERTING
       THEN
        :new.insert_os_user := SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER');
       END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What value would you expect this to have if you have in your APEX application?  It certainly wouldn't have the operating system user that is logged in to the browser, it wouldn't have the APEX username.  Depending on configuration, you could probably get all the APEX sessions to return a generic `oracle` user but I'm not sure that would do you any real good...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522627/way-to-figure-out-retrieve-windows-username-in-oracle-apex

Comment: Not an direct answer to the given example from the question - more an hint - but if you setup context in APEX during post_authentication, you will need to set something like "dbms_session.set_identifier(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER')||':'||sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_SESSION')" so that triggers that are called during post_authentication will run as the newly created session.